# end game not working

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit

I'm using a tutorial to create a game where if the rocketship is hit by an asteroid, the ship will show an image using SKEmitterNode and will blink then play a sound. This part of the game is working, however the game will not end. How do I fix this error?

Here's my code where I believe the error is

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (asteroidCategory | shipCategory)) {
        SKNode *asteroid, *spaceship;

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == shipCategory) {
            spaceship = contact.bodyA.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyB.node;
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion_large.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];

            SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1],
                                                   [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.1]]];
            SKAction *blinkForTime = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:6];
            [self.spaceship runAction:blinkForTime];

            NSString *explosionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RocketFlame" ofType:@"sks"];
            SKEmitterNode *explosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:explosionPath];
            CGVector emitterVector = CGVectorMake(spaceship.frame.size.width * 2.0, 0);
            explosion.particlePositionRange = emitterVector;
            [self.spaceship addChild:explosion];
        }
        else {
            spaceship = contact.bodyB.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyA.node;
            [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion_large.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];

            SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1],
                                                   [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.1]]];
            // SKAction *blinkForTime = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:6];
            [self.spaceship runAction:blink];

            NSString *explosionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RocketFlame" ofType:@"sks"];
            SKEmitterNode *explosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:explosionPath];
            CGVector emitterVector = CGVectorMake(spaceship.frame.size.width * 2.0, 0);
            explosion.particlePositionRange = emitterVector;
            [self.spaceship addChild:explosion];

        }

        [self asteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) asteroid didCollideWithasteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) spaceship];
    }
    else if (collision == (projectileCategory| asteroidCategory)) {

        SKNode *Projectile, *asteroid;

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory) {
            Projectile= contact.bodyA.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyB.node;
        }
        else {
            Projectile = contact.bodyB.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyA.node;
        }

        [self projectile:(SKSpriteNode *) Projectile didCollideWithasteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) asteroid];

        self.asteroidsDestroyed++;
        if (self.asteroidsDestroyed > 30) {
            SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
            SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:NO];
            [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I haven't read your code in detail yet but did you try to NSLog to see if you are colliding? There may be a problem with something else in your code.

Comment: There is nothing in the code which you have posted which would trigger the end of the game. What does the [self asteroid: didCollideWithAsteroid:] method do?

Comment: The NSLog is saying Hit every time a asteroid hits the spaceship. The didCollideWithAsteriod is suppose to check to see if the asteroid hits the spaceship and if it does then it will play the sound effect as well as show the explosion image on the spaceship

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The game is not ending because you are not calling the end-game transition in case of the collsion between the spaceship and asteroid as you do in the case where the collision is between the projectile and the asteroid.

```
- (void)didBeginContact:(SKPhysicsContact *)contact
{
    uint32_t collision = (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask | contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask);

    if (collision == (asteroidCategory | shipCategory)) {
        SKNode *asteroid, *spaceship;

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == shipCategory) {
            spaceship = contact.bodyA.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyB.node;

        }
        else {
            spaceship = contact.bodyB.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyA.node;
        }

        [self runAction:[SKAction playSoundFileNamed:@"explosion_large.caf" waitForCompletion:NO]];

        SKAction *blink = [SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction fadeOutWithDuration:0.1],
                                               [SKAction fadeInWithDuration:0.1]]];
        SKAction *blinkForTime = [SKAction repeatAction:blink count:6];
        [self.spaceship runAction:blinkForTime];

        NSString *explosionPath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"RocketFlame" ofType:@"sks"];
        SKEmitterNode *explosion = [NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithFile:explosionPath];
        CGVector emitterVector = CGVectorMake(spaceship.frame.size.width * 2.0, 0);
        explosion.particlePositionRange = emitterVector;
        [self.spaceship addChild:explosion];

        [self asteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) asteroid didCollideWithasteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) spaceship]; //What does this do?

        [self runAction:[SKAction sequence:@[[SKAction waitForDuration:3.0], [SKAction runBlock:^{
            [self gameEndedWithSuccess:NO];
        }]]]];
    }
    else if (collision == (projectileCategory| asteroidCategory)) {

        SKNode *Projectile, *asteroid;

        if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask == asteroidCategory) {
            Projectile= contact.bodyA.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyB.node;
        }
        else {
            Projectile = contact.bodyB.node;
            asteroid = contact.bodyA.node;
        }

        [self projectile:(SKSpriteNode *) Projectile didCollideWithasteroid:(SKSpriteNode *) asteroid];

        self.asteroidsDestroyed++;
        if (self.asteroidsDestroyed > 30) {
            [self gameEndedWithSuccess:YES];
        }
    }
}

-(void) gameEndedWithSuccess:(BOOL)success
{
    SKTransition *reveal = [SKTransition flipHorizontalWithDuration:0.5];
    SKScene * gameOverScene = [[GameOverScene alloc] initWithSize:self.size won:success];
    [self.view presentScene:gameOverScene transition: reveal];
}
```

Comment: This worked! You were missing one brace and I commented out the line where you asked about what the line does. Thank you very much!